# XAMARIN - An Exception Occurred While Rendering The Control

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I'm writing for iOS&Android. I want to run the design preview screen, but this error is coming to the screen. When I want to open a new project and see the design screen, it works.

[image]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```xml
<StackLayout>

    <Entry x:Name="entry_name" Text="deneme1" Placeholder="Ad"></Entry>
    <Entry x:Name ="entry_lastname" Text="deneme2" Placeholder="Soyad"></Entry>
    <Button x:Name="btn_add" Clicked="btn_add_Clicked" Text="EKLE"></Button>
    <ListView x:Name="EmployeeView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ad}" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding soyad}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</StackLayout>
```

Comment: You cannot see the design as it is having a list view control added.. the list view is not a static data control.

Comment: I wrote the same XML code for the project I just created, but it doesn't work in my own project.